# Plotting a Graph in R

Tags: r, random-forest, mnist

I used this site as a reference
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/how-to-build-a-handwritten-digit-classifier-with-r-and-random-forests/

to write a handwritten digit classifier using R with random forests.

Is it possible to build a plot of the colMeans obtained at the end of the code? The MNIST train and test datasets (that you can find in the link above) don't have any column headings.
I'm new to R and still learning. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
library(readr)

#loading the train and test sets of MNIST dataset 
train_set <- read_csv("mnist_train.csv", col_names = FALSE)
test_set <- read_csv("mnist_test.csv", col_names = FALSE)

#extracting the labels
#converting digits to factors
train_labels <- as.factor(train_set[, 1]$X1)
test_labels <- as.factor(test_set[, 1]$X1)

#printing the first 10 labels
head(train_labels, 10)

#printing number of records for each digit (0 to 9)
summary(train_labels)

#importing random forest
library(randomForest)

#training the model
rf <- randomForest(x = train_set, y = train_labels, xtest = test_set, ntree = 50)
rf

#1- error rate
#represents the accuracy 
1 - mean(rf$err.rate)

#importing dplyr
library(dplyr)

#error rate for every digit
err_df <- as.data.frame(rf$err.rate)
err_df %>%
    select(-"OOB") %>%
    colMeans()
```

Output of colMeans[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4xjZ.png)

Comment: What kind of plot would you like to see? `colMeans` is your y-axis? If so, what is your x-axis?

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti x-axis would be the digits, 0 through 9 and y-axis would be colMeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified your code by subsetting quite a bit both the train and test set to speed up the analysis. You are free to comment/delete the related lines. Please have a look at the code below and tell me if this is what you are looking for.

```r
library(readr)
#importing dplyr
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#importing random forest
library(randomForest)
#> randomForest 4.6-14
#> Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'randomForest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     combine
library(ggplot2)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggplot2'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:randomForest':
#> 
#>     margin


#loading the train and test sets of MNIST dataset 
train_set <- read_csv("~/Downloads/mnist_train.csv", col_names = FALSE)
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double()
#> )
#> ℹ Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.
test_set <- read_csv("~/Downloads/mnist_test.csv", col_names = FALSE)
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double()
#> )
#> ℹ Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.

#extracting the labels
#converting digits to factors
train_labels <- as.factor(train_set[, 1]$X1)
test_labels <- as.factor(test_set[, 1]$X1)

#printing the first 10 labels
head(train_labels, 10)
#>  [1] 5 0 4 1 9 2 1 3 1 4
#> Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

#printing number of records for each digit (0 to 9)
summary(train_labels)
#>    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
#> 5923 6742 5958 6131 5842 5421 5918 6265 5851 5949

# reducing size
train_set <- train_set[ 1:1000, ]
train_labels <- train_labels[ 1:1000 ]
test_set <- test_set[ 1:100, ]
test_labels <- test_labels[ 1:100 ]

#training the model
rf <- randomForest(x = train_set, y = train_labels, xtest = test_set, ntree = 50)
rf
#> 
#> Call:
#>  randomForest(x = train_set, y = train_labels, xtest = test_set,      ntree = 50) 
#>                Type of random forest: classification
#>                      Number of trees: 50
#> No. of variables tried at each split: 28
#> 
#>         OOB estimate of  error rate: 11.6%
#> Confusion matrix:
#>    0   1  2  3  4  5  6   7  8  9 class.error
#> 0 96   0  0  0  0  0  1   0  0  0  0.01030928
#> 1  0 112  1  1  0  1  0   0  0  1  0.03448276
#> 2  2   6 82  0  2  0  1   4  2  0  0.17171717
#> 3  0   1  2 78  2  5  1   1  2  1  0.16129032
#> 4  0   0  1  0 94  1  2   1  1  5  0.10476190
#> 5  0   0  1  8  3 77  1   0  0  2  0.16304348
#> 6  1   0  1  0  2  2 86   1  1  0  0.08510638
#> 7  0   3  3  2  4  0  0 102  0  3  0.12820513
#> 8  0   1  1  3  1  6  1   1 71  2  0.18390805
#> 9  1   0  0  1  4  1  1   5  1 86  0.14000000

#1- error rate
#represents the accuracy 
1 - mean(rf$err.rate)
#> [1] 0.8012579


#error rate for every digit
err_df <- as.data.frame(rf$err.rate)
mymeans <- err_df %>%
  select(-"OOB") %>%
  colMeans()

# I build a data.frame containing the indexes and the means
toplot <- data.frame( index = seq_len( length( mymeans ) ) - 1,
                      col_means = mymeans )

# this is to plot via ggplot2
ggplot( toplot, aes( x = index, y = col_means ) ) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_len( length( mymeans ) ) - 1 )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted @FrancescoGrossetti